# grep lines before and after in aix/ksh shell

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ksh, aix

I want to extract lines before and after a matched pattern.

eg: if the file contents are as follows

```
absbasdakjkglksagjgj
sajlkgsgjlskjlasj
hello
lkgjkdsfjlkjsgklks
klgdsgklsdgkldskgdsg
```

I need find hello and display line before and after 'hello'

the output should be

```
sajlkgsgjlskjlasj
hello
lkgjkdsfjlkjsgklks
```

This is possible with GNU but i need a method that works in AIX / KSH SHELL WHERE NO GNU IS INSTALLED.

Comment: Cannot you use the `-A`, `-B` and `-C` options?

Comment: it doesnt work on AIX SHELL. GNU is not installed. (KSH SHELL)

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n '/hello/{x;G;N;p;};h' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found it is generally less frustrating to build the GNU coreutils once, and benefit from many more features http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/

Answer (score 0):

Since you'll have Perl on the machine, you could use the following code, but you'd probably do better to install the GNU utilities.  This has options `-b n1` for lines  before and `-f n1` for lines following the match.  It works with PCRE matches (so if you want case-insensitive matching, add an `i` after the regex instead using a `-i` option.  I haven't implemented `-v` or `-l`; I didn't need those.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
#
# @(#)$Id: sgrep.pl,v 1.7 2013/01/28 02:07:18 jleffler Exp $
#
# Perl-based SGREP (special grep) command
# 
# Print lines around the line that matches (by default, 3 before and 3 after).
# By default, include file names if more than one file to search.
#
# Options:
# -b n1     Print n1 lines before match
# -f n2     Print n2 lines following match
# -n        Print line numbers
# -h        Do not print file names
# -H        Do     print file names

use warnings;
use strict;
use constant debug => 0;
use Getopt::Std;
my(%opts);

sub usage
{
    print STDERR "Usage: $0 [-hnH] [-b n1] [-f n2] pattern [file ...]\n";
    exit 1;
}

usage unless getopts('hnf:b:H', \%opts);
usage unless @ARGV >= 1;

if ($opts{h} && $opts{H})
{
    print STDERR "$0: mutually exclusive options -h and -H specified\n";
    exit 1;
}

my $op = shift;

print "# regex = $op\n" if debug;

# print file names if -h omitted and more than one argument
$opts{F} = (defined $opts{H} || (!defined $opts{h} and scalar @ARGV > 1)) ? 1 : 0;
$opts{n} = 0 unless defined $opts{n};

my $before = (defined $opts{b}) ? $opts{b} + 0 : 3;
my $after  = (defined $opts{f}) ? $opts{f} + 0 : 3;

print "# before = $before; after = $after\n" if debug;

my @lines = (); # Accumulated lines
my $tail  = 0;  # Line number of last line in list
my $tbp_1 = 0;  # First line to be printed
my $tbp_2 = 0;  # Last line to be printed

# Print lines from @lines in the range $tbp_1 .. $tbp_2,
# leaving $leave lines in the array for future use.
sub print_leaving
{
    my ($leave) = @_;
    while (scalar(@lines) > $leave)
    {
        my $line = shift @lines;
        my $curr = $tail - scalar(@lines);
        if ($tbp_1 <= $curr && $curr <= $tbp_2)
        {
            print "$ARGV:" if $opts{F};
            print "$curr:" if $opts{n};
            print $line;
        }
    }
}

# General logic:
# Accumulate each line at end of @lines.
# ** If current line matches, record range that needs printing
# ** When the line array contains enough lines, pop line off front and,
#    if it needs printing, print it.
# At end of file, empty line array, printing requisite accumulated lines.

while (<>)
{
    # Add this line to the accumulated lines
    push @lines, $_;
    $tail = $.;

    printf "# array: N = %d, last = $tail: %s", scalar(@lines), $_ if debug > 1;

    if (m/$op/o)
    {
        # This line matches - set range to be printed
        my $lo = $. - $before;
        $tbp_1 = $lo if ($lo > $tbp_2);
        $tbp_2 = $. + $after;
        print "# $. MATCH: print range $tbp_1 .. $tbp_2\n" if debug;
    }

    # Print out any accumulated lines that need printing
    # Leave $before lines in array.
    print_leaving($before);
}
continue
{
    if (eof)
    {
        # Print out any accumulated lines that need printing
        print_leaving(0);
        # Reset for next file
        close ARGV;
        $tbp_1 = 0;
        $tbp_2 = 0;
        $tail  = 0;
        @lines = ();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a situation where I was stuck with a slow telnet session on a tablet, believe it or not, and I couldn't write a Perl script very easily with that keyboard. I came up with this hacky maneuver that worked in a pinch for me with AIX's limited grep. This won't work well if your grep returns hundreds of lines, but if you just need one line and one or two above/below it, this could do it. First I ran this:

`cat -n filename |grep criteria`

By including the `-n` flag, I see the line number of the data I'm seeking, like this:

```
2543 my crucial data
```

Since `cat` gives the line number 2 spaces before and 1 space after, I could grep for the *line number* right before it like this:

`cat -n filename |grep "  2542 "`

I ran this a couple of times to give me lines 2542 and 2544 that bookended line 2543. Like I said, it's definitely fallable, like if you have reams of data that might have "  2542 " all over the place, but just to grab a couple of quick lines, it worked well.